# In pytorch , how can I release all gpu memory when the program still run?

Tags: memory, pytorch, gpu

```py
import time
from torchvision.models import resnet18
import GPUtil
class AAA:
    def load(self):
        device = torch.device('cuda:0')

        self.dummy_tensor_4 = torch.randn(120, 3, 512, 512).float().to(device)  # 120*3*512*512*4/1000/1000 = 377.48M
        self.dummy_tensor_5 = torch.randn(10, 3, 512, 512).float().to(device)  # 80*3*512*512*4/1000/1000 = 251.64M
        self.model = resnet18(pretrained=True).to(device)        
        self.X = self.model(self.dummy_tensor_5)        
        time.sleep(5)
        
    def release(self):
        del self.dummy_tensor_4
        del self.dummy_tensor_5
        del self.model
        del self.X
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
      
A = AAA()
A.load()
A.release()
del A



torch.cuda.empty_cache()
print("start waitting")
for i in range(30):
    GPUtil.showUtilization()  
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is my code.
If I use "self.X = self.model(self.dummy_tensor_5) ", my gpu memory can't release clear. Am I missing something to delete?
If I use without "self.X = self.model(self.dummy_tensor_5) ", gpu memory release perfect.

Comment: You seem to be saying that using "self.X = self.model(self.dummy_tensor_5) " prevents memory release and also works - is there a typo in your question?

Comment: Thank you! I have typo and I have corrected